# Is it possible to use Openstreetmaps tile server to serve tiles to mapbox gl with a docker image

Tags: docker, mapbox, openstreetmap, vector-tiles

is it possible to serve tiles to a mapbox instance using a openstreetmap-tile-server docker image.

This link is a link to set up the server (https://switch2osm.org/serving-tiles/using-a-docker-container/).

The example it provides is a map produced on leaflet but I was wondering if there was a way to modify it so it would use mapbox instead? the server has produced xyz formatted png files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to use the tile server hosted on your docker container.

In that case, [this example](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/map-tiles/) would work.

Comment: Yes, I did this yesterday and forgot to update this question, applying that raster style and then linking it to the server works perfectly